# An Int argument in the ArrayList, what is it?

Tags: java

What is the difference between this:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and this:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(3);
```

I just tested the Array and I really see no difference.. I always see people using a number there, what is it for ?

Comment: When you have have questions like these, you should refer to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int%29) first.

Comment: I kind of want to give +1 for a good username...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Initial Capacity](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29)
Generally used to create lists with some storage amount ahead of time so java doesn't have to do it for you when you add elements.  Or if you know exactly how many entries it will have.

To be clear, the list still doesn't contain any elements when it's created this way, but the space for those elements is reserved.

Answer (score 2):

It's the initial size of your list. If you don't give any argument, there will be a default intitial size.
By the way, reading the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) will answer all those questions.

Answer (score 1):

All the number does is set the initial capacity for the arraylist.  The arraylist will expand as needed, but if you already know that you'll at least need X slots, you can put X in then parenthesis to allocate that number of slots right from the start.

Refer to the constructor for ArrayLists here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

When you use the second code, It initially allocates 3 elements and the first will allocates 10 elements (capacity).

> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)